# AutoLISP, How to export my selected polylines to a CSV with a name

Tags: lisp, autocad, cad, autolisp

I have this code below. It exports the selected polylines lenght to a CSV but **it does not give it a name** so i cant make a difference between two(or more) types of polyline.

My question is how to modify this code in order to be able to export the lenghts **with the name of the linetype**.

For example: I loaded ZIGZAG and TRACKS linetype, next I run my function and select all of the drawn polylines and I want to see in my CSV that which linetype is how long by name.

```
 (defun c:Polyline_számoló (/ s i e l fn)
      (if (and(setq s (ssget '((0 . "LWPOLYLINE"))))
          (setq fn (getfiled "Create Output File" "" "csv" 1)))
        (progn
          (setq s (_SortSSByXValue s))
          (setq i (sslength s))
          (while (setq e(ssname s (setq i (1- i))))
        (setq l (cons (vla-get-length (vlax-ename->vla-object e)) l))
        (ssdel e s)
          )
        )
      )
      (setq l (list (cd:CON_All2Str l nil)))
      (if (LM:WriteCSV l fn)
                    (startapp "explorer" fn)
                )
      (princ)
    )
    
    
    (defun cd:CON_All2Str (Lst Mode)
      (mapcar
        (function
          (lambda (%)
            (if Mode
              (vl-prin1-to-string %)
              (vl-princ-to-string %)
            )
          )
        )
        Lst
      )
    )
    
    
    
    (defun _SortSSByXValue (ss / lst i e add)
      (if (eq (type ss) 'PICKSET)
        (progn
          (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
            (setq lst (cons (cons (setq e (ssname ss (setq i (1- i))))
                                  (cadr (assoc 10 (entget e)))
                            )
                            lst
                      )
            )
          )
          (setq add (ssadd))
          (foreach e (vl-sort lst (function (lambda (a b) (< (cdr a) (cdr b))))) (ssadd (car e) add))
          (if (> (sslength add) 0)
            add
          )
        )
      )
    )
    
    
    (defun LM:writecsv ( lst csv / des sep )
        (if (setq des (open csv "w"))
            (progn
                (setq sep (cond ((vl-registry-read "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\International" "sList")) (",")))
                (foreach row lst (write-line (LM:lst->csv row sep) des))
                (close des)
                t
            )
        )
    )
    
    
    
    (defun LM:lst->csv ( lst sep )
        (if (cdr lst)
            (strcat (LM:csv-addquotes (car lst) sep) sep (LM:lst->csv (cdr lst) sep))
            (LM:csv-addquotes (car lst) sep)
        )
    )
    
    
    
    (defun LM:csv-addquotes ( str sep / pos )
        (cond
            (   (wcmatch str (strcat "*[`" sep "\"]*"))
                (setq pos 0)    
                (while (setq pos (vl-string-position 34 str pos))
                    (setq str (vl-string-subst "\"\"" "\"" str pos)
                          pos (+ pos 2)
                    )
                )
                (strcat "\"" str "\"")
            )
            (   str   )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lisp function that will export a csv file.
The csv file contains two sections:

1.) a length summary by linetype name
2.) an individual line summary with length and linetype

csv example:

```
--Length Summary By LineType--
LineType,Length
CENTER,739.97
HIDDEN,1858.61
--Length Breakdown By Individual Line--
LineType,Length
CENTER,246.656
HIDDEN,309.768
HIDDEN,309.768
CENTER,246.656
HIDDEN,309.768
HIDDEN,309.768
CENTER,246.656
HIDDEN,309.768
HIDDEN,309.768
```

Lisp code

```
;;www.cadwiki.net

(defun c:test (/ s i e l fn CSVSTRING CSVSTRINGLIST DATAITEM individualLineDataList LINELENGTH LINETYPE VLAOBJECT NEWASSOC NEWLENGTH PREVIOUSLENGTH lineTypeToLengthAssoc SUMMARYENTRY
              )
  (if (and (setq s (ssget '((0 . "LWPOLYLINE"))))
           (setq fn (getfiled "Create Output File" "" "csv" 1))
      )
    (progn
      (setq s (_SortSSByXValue s))
      (setq i (sslength s))
      (setq individualLineDataList (list))

      (while (setq e (ssname s (setq i (1- i))))
        (setq vlaObject (vlax-ename->vla-object e))
        (setq lineType (vla-get-linetype vlaObject))
        (setq lineLength (vla-get-length vlaObject))
        (setq dataItem (list lineType lineLength))
        (setq individualLineDataList (cons dataItem individualLineDataList))
        (setq summaryEntry (assoc lineType lineTypeToLengthAssoc))
        (if (/= summaryEntry nil)
          (progn
            (setq previousLength (cdr summaryEntry))
            (setq newLength (+ previousLength lineLength))
            (setq newAssoc (cons lineType newLength))
            (setq lineTypeToLengthAssoc (REMOVE-ASSOC-BY-KEY lineType lineTypeToLengthAssoc))
            (setq lineTypeToLengthAssoc (cons newAssoc lineTypeToLengthAssoc))
          )
          (progn
            (setq newAssoc (cons lineType lineLength))
            (setq lineTypeToLengthAssoc (cons newAssoc lineTypeToLengthAssoc))
          )
        )
        (ssdel e s)
      )
    )
  )
  (setq csvStringList (list (list "--Length Summary By LineType--")))
  (setq csvStringList (cons (list "LineType" "Length") csvStringList))
  (foreach assocItem lineTypeToLengthAssoc
    (setq csvString (summaryAssocToStringList assocItem))
    (setq csvStringList (cons csvString csvStringList))
  )
  (setq csvStringList (cons (list "--Length Breakdown By Individual Line--") csvStringList))
  (setq csvStringList (cons (list "LineType" "Length") csvStringList))
  (foreach item individualLineDataList
    (setq csvString (cd:CON_All2Str item nil))
    (setq csvStringList (cons csvString csvStringList))
  )
  (setq csvStringList (reverse csvStringList))
  (if (LM:WriteCSV csvStringList fn)
    (startapp "explorer" fn)
  )
  (princ)
)

(defun REMOVE-ASSOC-BY-KEY (assocKey assocList / newAssocList item)
  (setq newAssocList nil)
  (foreach item assocList
    (if (not (= (car item) assocKey))
      (setq newAssocList (append newAssocList (list item)))
    )
  )
  newAssocList
)


(defun summaryAssocToStringList (assocItem / LINELENGTH LINETYPE STRINGLIST)
  (setq lineType (car assocItem))
  (setq lineLength (cdr assocItem))
  (setq stringList (list lineType (rtos lineLength 2 2)))
)

(defun cd:CON_All2Str (Lst Mode)
  (mapcar
    (function
      (lambda (%)
        (if Mode
          (vl-prin1-to-string %)
          (vl-princ-to-string %)
        )
      )
    )
    Lst
  )
)



(defun _SortSSByXValue (ss / lst i e add)
  (if (eq (type ss) 'PICKSET)
    (progn
      (repeat (setq i (sslength ss))
        (setq lst (cons (cons (setq e (ssname ss (setq i (1- i))))
                              (cadr (assoc 10 (entget e)))
                        )
                        lst
                  )
        )
      )
      (setq add (ssadd))
      (foreach e (vl-sort lst (function (lambda (a b) (< (cdr a) (cdr b))))) (ssadd (car e) add))
      (if (> (sslength add) 0)
        add
      )
    )
  )
)


(defun LM:writecsv (lst csv / des sep)
  (if (setq des (open csv "w"))
    (progn
      (setq sep (cond ((vl-registry-read "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Control Panel\\International" "sList"))
                      (",")
                )
      )
      (foreach row lst (write-line (LM:lst->csv row sep) des))
      (close des)
      t
    )
  )
)



(defun LM:lst->csv (lst sep)
  (if (cdr lst)
    (strcat (LM:csv-addquotes (car lst) sep) sep (LM:lst->csv (cdr lst) sep))
    (LM:csv-addquotes (car lst) sep)
  )
)



(defun LM:csv-addquotes (str sep / pos)
  (cond
    ((wcmatch str (strcat "*[`" sep "\"]*"))
     (setq pos 0)
     (while (setq pos (vl-string-position 34 str pos))
       (setq str (vl-string-subst "\"\"" "\"" str pos)
             pos (+ pos 2)
       )
     )
     (strcat "\"" str "\"")
    )
    (str)
  )
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).